# Elm "cannot find module"

Tags: elm

I'm fairly new in Elm. It's interesting to see a functional language which allows you to develop front-end stuff. Now even if I am following the steps described [here](http://elm-lang.org/get-started) nicely, I still have problems with modules.

The code is

```
module Main where

import Html exposing ( Html )
import Signal

main : Signal Html.Html
main = Html.text "This should work."
       |> Signal.constant
```

I have used `elm-reactor -a='localhost'` to be able to view my output. But I am getting an error, that module 'HTML' cannot be found:

```
I cannot find find module 'Html'.

Module 'Main' is trying to import it.

Potential problems could be:
  * Misspelled the module name
  * Need to add a source directory or new dependency to elm-package.json
```

(note the double "find" hehe)
The fix suggestion didn't help me. Or it could be that I'm not understanding the use of the .json file correctly.

elm-package.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "summary": "testing elm",
    "license": "BSD3",
    "source-directories": [
        ".",
        "./bin/"
    ],
    "exposed-modules": [],
    "dependencies": {
        "elm-lang/core": "3.0.0 <= v < 4.0.0"
    },
    "elm-version": "0.16.0 <= v < 0.17.0"
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my file tree.

[image: elm file tree]

Maybe it behaves differently than how Haskell is threatening the modules.

How can I solve this - eh simple? - problem.
Or is my `elm-package.json` just configured incorrectly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Update for Elm 0.17**

In 0.17, the Html package has been moved to [`elm-lang/html`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.0.0/). Run the following command from the terminal to install it:

```
elm package install elm-lang/html
```

You should also remove the `evancz/elm-html` package from `elm-package.json` because it no longer exists as of 0.17.

For more information about the upgrading from 0.16 to 0.17, please see the [0.17 announcement](http://elm-lang.org/blog/farewell-to-frp).

**Original Answer for Elm 0.16**

Your `elm-package.json` configuration is missing the [`evancz/elm-html`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/latest) package, which exposes `Html`. You can use elm's package manager to install dependencies rather than editing `elm-package.json` directly.

From the terminal, type the following:

```
elm package install evancz/elm-html
```

You will also be prompted to install a few other missing dependencies required by `evancz/elm-html`. Running this command will update your `elm-package.json` file as well as pull down the missing packages from the internet and install them in the standard `elm-stuff/packages` directory.

[More info on the `elm-package` tool can be found here.](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-package/blob/master/README.md)

You can browse elm packages online at [package.elm-lang.org](http://package.elm-lang.org/). The sidebar has a Popular Packages section which contains the `evancz/elm-html` package mentioned here.

Comment: ah, you beat me to an answer. I think yours is slightly better. Can you add my mention of the Popular Packages in the sidebar of package.elm-lang.org? Then my answer will become obsolete and I can remove it.

Comment: Good point, @Apanatshka. I've added the link and mention of Popular Packages. Thanks!

Comment: Aha. I thought that Html is a part of the core. It is strange that i didn't have found that link yet. It's hidden behind "community packages" [here](http://elm-lang.org/docs), which i read as "custom packages" like plugins ... That the HTML is not a part of the core didn't got mentioned somewhere in [this tutorial](https://github.com/evancz/start-app) or in examples (it uses online editor) though.

Comment: @KarelG As of Elm 0.17, it's now part of the core. =)

Comment: this is outdated. With Elm 0.17 it would be `elm package install elm-lang/html`

Comment: I've updated the answer with 0.17 info. Thanks for the reminder, @therealmarv