# I cannot find module 'Html.App' elm v0.18

Tags: functional-programming, elm

When upgrading from elm `v0.17.1` to `v0.18` we see the following error:

I cannot find module 'Html.App'.

the `App` method *was* available in `v1.1.0` of the `Html` package
see: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.1.0/Html-App

but *appears* to have been *removed* from `v2.0.0` http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0 *hence the semver version bump*...

> **Note**: *related* to: [Elm "cannot find module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201205/elm-cannot-find-module) (*but this is **specific** to `Html.App`*)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The contents of `Html.App` were moved to the `Html` package in version 0.18. You can simply import from `Html` and remove references to `Html.App`.

From the [upgrade instructions](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.18.md):

> [`elm-lang/html`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/latest) collapsed `Html.App` into `Html`. So you need to remove any import `Html.App` imports and refer to `Html.program` instead.

[See the release notes here](http://elm-lang.org/blog/the-perfect-bug-report).